# How to include python directory to CMakeList.txt file

Tags: python, cmake, cmakelists-options

This is my CMakeList.txt File, I want to include python3.9 directory and want to link all headers and libraries under python3.9 path.When i run it with command line i used the following command

```
 g++ data.cpp -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/python3.9 -lpython3.9 -I/opt/mongo-cxx-driver/include/mongocxx/v_noabi -I/opt/mongo-cxx-driver/include/libmongoc-1.0   -I/opt/mongo-cxx-driver/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi -I/opt/mongo-cxx-driver/include/libbson-1.0   -L/opt/mongo-cxx-driver/lib64 -lmongocxx -lbsoncxx
```

It is working fine with the above command but when I am using following CMakeList.txt file for build. but it is not linking my libraries of python. What i am doing wrong? please help

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
 set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
 add_subdirectory(../dlib dlib_build)
 add_executable(testmongo data.cpp)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/usr/include/python3.9")
find_package(libmongocxx REQUIRED)
find_package(libbsoncxx REQUIRED)
include_directories(${LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${LIBBSONCXX_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories("/opt/mongo-cxx-driver/include/mongocxx/v_noabi")
include_directories("/opt/mongo-cxx-driver/include//bsoncxx/v_noabi")
include_directories("/opt/mongo-cxx-driver/include/libmongoc-1.0")
include_directories("/opt/mongo-cxx-driver/include/libbson-1.0")
include_directories("/opt/mongo-cxx-driver/lib64")
target_link_libraries(testmongo ${LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(testmongo ${LIBBSONCXX_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(testmongo dlib::dlib)
target_link_libraries(testmongo ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

Everything is linking fine except python library linking

Comment: I changed last line as  "target_link_libraries(testmongo python3.9) and it started working

Answer (score 0):

`include_directories` affect targets declared after it.

```
add_executable(blabla ...)      # does not use /some/dir
include_directories(/some/dir)  # change!
add_executable(blabla2 ...)     # uses /some/dir!
```

But do not use `include_directories` at all. Use `target_include_directories` instead.

Comment: but everything is working fine except Python linking library. What am i doing wrong with python library linking?

Comment: also target_include_directories is giving error that it has more parameters than one